# Updates to datatable not saving

Tags: vb.net, datatable, oledb

I have a database editing program, and need to give users the ability to edit the definitions of existing queries.  Changes appear to be applied to the DataTable appropriately, but they are not actually saved.

```
' schemaTable will be set to one of the following values before calling this method
schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Views, Nothing)
or
schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, Nothing)

Public Sub UpdateQueryDefinition(ByRef schemaTable As DataTable, _
                                 ByRef SQL As String, _
                                 ByVal QName As String, _
                                 ByVal View As Boolean)

Dim existingqueryname As String
Dim existingquerydefinition As String
Dim qrydefinitionindex As Integer

For each row As DataRow In schemaTable.Rows

     existingqueryname = row.ItemArray(2).ToString.ToUpper
     If View Then
        ' Column index for query definition is 3 for Views
        qrydefinitionindex = 3
     Else
        ' Not a view, then we're a procedure.  The Definition is column index 4
        qrydefinitionindex = 4
     End If
     existingquerydefinition = row.ItemArray(qrydefinitionindex).ToString.ToUpper

     ' See if the current query in schemaTable is the query we want to modify
     If existingqueryname = QName.ToUpper Then

        SQL = ' User input retrieved and set here

        ' Set query definition in schemaTable = to user input of new query
        row.Item(qrydefinitionindex) = SQL
        row.AcceptChanges()

' At this point, if you reference row.Item(qrydefinitionindex) it will indeed = SQL
' but the query is not actually modified in the .mdb

        Exit For
     End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Am I overlooking something?  Why are the changes not being reflected in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable is a disconnected object, independent from database connection. Whatever changes you do to it - stay in memory only. You need to write additional logic to write data back to the database.

Comment: Thanks, gotta love overlooking something simple =).